# Is there a way to define JS functions in arbitrary order?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I like the functional programming idea that each function serves just one purpose etc...

Though, I don't get how to make my code human-readable in terms of ordering functions.

```js
// writeParagraph.js

const writeWord = (wordArgs) => {
  // do stuff with wordArgs
  return word
}

const writeSentence = (sentenceArgs) => {
  const sentence = sentenceArgs.map(writeWords)
  return sentence
}

export const writeParagraph = (paragraphArgs) => {
  const paragraph = paragraphArgs.map(writeSentence)
  return paragraph
}
```

Whenever I'll be opening the `writeParagraph.js` to explore what is in it, I'll be looking for the `export const writeParagraph` part. And to read it, I'll have to go to the `writeSentence`, which is above, not below. As a human being, I get used to reading top to bottom. Is there way to structure functional code to read top to bottom.

Comment: What about using `function(){}` to define the functions?

Comment: @AdamAzad I don't see what this should be necessary, because the dependent functions are only accessed when the function is invoked, and at this stage the entire script has been interpreted.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer a different order, you can just change it:

```
export const writeParagraph = (paragraphArgs) => {
  const paragraph = paragraphArgs.map(writeSentence)
  return paragraph
} 

const writeSentence = (sentenceArgs) => {
  const sentence = sentenceArgs.map(writeWords)
  return sentence
}

const writeWord = (wordArgs) => {
  // do stuff with wordArgs
  return word
}
```

This works because all the functions are declared in the same scope, and can access each other.

If your linter now complains about potential use-before-define (even if you are not doing that), you can either disable that rule (if you know what you're doing) or use proper declarations instead:

```
export function writeParagraph(paragraphArgs) {
  const paragraph = paragraphArgs.map(writeSentence)
  return paragraph
} 

function writeSentence(sentenceArgs) {
  const sentence = sentenceArgs.map(writeWords)
  return sentence
}

function writeWord(wordArgs) {
  // do stuff with wordArgs
  return word
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Code order can be subjective.

Some cultures read from the back of the book to the right.
Some read right to left.

I would think that this is why comments were invented.

Put a comment block at the top explaining the order of your code.

Comment: _"Code order can be subjective"_ - And that's not an answer but a comment